# does package-lock.json prevent updates?

Tags: node.js, package.json

My app is node v4, I wrote it back on v4 and have never needed to update it (if it ain't broke...). That is, until one of the dependencies removed v4 support in a minor version update.

I read that there is this idea of `package-lock.json` in 5.x+

Will the `package-lock.jso`n concept prevent the scenario of minor versions breaking my app when I have to reinstall from source?

I basically want to verify a `node_modules` is working as expected, and every time I run `npm install` I get the same `node_modules` I did originally, even if a dependency five deep decides to update their package I don't want it.

Answer (score 2):

As you already said in the comments, the answer is Yes.

And for your dependencies dependencies, running `npm install` will install the versions specified in their respective package.json (they don't have package-lock.json as it is not published, but they could have a [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/shrinkwrap.json)) unless you run a [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update).

In short terms, you would only run in a scenario you don't want to if you run `npm update`, but `npm install` won't give you troubles.

By the way, you can easily replicate that behaviour by copying your `package.json` to 2 environment where you have the 2 versions of node that you need.

Comment: I don't have two versions of node. I just have node v4.5 but when the owner of a package randomly dropped v4 and v5 support, my application broke when it got deployed (I use amazon beanstalk so it can go through many npm installs in a month ).

So the issue before was one of my dependencies's dependency had in their package.json  `tar: ^4` which  node-tar dropped v4 and v5 support without a major release, therefore my app broke despite keeping the same package.json

You seem to misunderstand my scenario because you think just by keeping the same package.json i could of avoided the issue.

Comment: package-lock.json also covers dependencies of dependencies. so there should be no way to accidentally fetch newer version of 5th level dependency that does not support version of Node you use. or telling the truth it's possible but author should publish changes with exactly the same version in package.json that seems near to impossible

Answer (score 1):

package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.

This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and serves various purposes:

Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies.

Provide a facility for users to "time-travel" to previous states of node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.

To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable source control diffs.

And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

One key detail about package-lock.json is that it cannot be published, and it will be ignored if found in any place other than the toplevel package. It shares a format with npm-shrinkwrap.json(5), which is essentially the same file, but allows publication. This is not recommended unless deploying a CLI tool or otherwise using the publication process for producing production packages.

If both package-lock.json and npm-shrinkwrap.json are present in the root of a package, package-lock.json will be completely ignored.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the definition, and while it is almost obvious that the answer to my question is "Yes".. I want to make sure.  Because I read in that 5.2.x  that package.json can override package-lock.json .. So my direct dependencies can update, but my dependencies' dependencies cannot?